# Convert Line breaks to html break for all field getters in Symfony project

Tags: symfony1

I am working on a Symfony project and I currently have this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/\n/','<br />', $review->getComments()); ?>
```

and would very much like to be able to make all getters add html line breaks so i don't have to pepper my code with preg_replace. the $object->getFieldname methods are work automatically so I am looking to extend this somewhere to globally add a new method. What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best idea would be to add a getCommentsHtml() method onto your review object, which does something like:

```
return preg_replace('/\n/','<br />', $this->getComments());
```

Then you can use $review->getCommentsHtml() to format them using HTML.  Also as Charlie mentioned, maybe str_replace would be better to use, as using a regular expression to change \n's into <br />'s may be a little bit of overkill :)

So if you don't want to have your code littered with replaces like this, I think putting a helper method on the classes that you'd like to format nicely would be the best way to go :)

Comment: This is close to what I am wanting, I apologize for not making my questions a bit clear I have updated it.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like everyone forgot about [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) which is a function that does exactly that in PHP.

```
nl2br($review->getComments());
```

**EDIT:** At the time of this writing, everyone else uses `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
str_replace("\n",'<br />', $review->getComments());
```